# Xml DeSerialization - Array Elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

lookin my XML example, how I do to Deserialize it? 
But I need to Deserialize the Xml Element array. How I do it?

```
<hotels num="1">
<hotel num="1" item="2"></hotel>
<hotel num="2" item="2"></hotel>
<hotel num="3" item="2"></hotel>
<hotel num="4" item="2"></hotel>
<hotel num="5" item="2"></hotel>
</hotels>

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("hotels")]
public class Hotels
{
[XmlElement("id")]
public string id {  get; set; }
[XmlElement("hotel")]
public Hotel hotel { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("hotel")]
public class Hotel
{
[XmlElement("id")]
public string id {  get; set; }
[XmlElement("item")]
public string item {  get; set; }
}
```

Comment: whats the DataAnotation is using to determine that element is xml array?

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem, but the `Hotel` property on the `Hotels` class should probably be changed to a `List<Hotel>` or `Hotel[]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this:

```
[XmlRoot("hotels")]
public class HotelData
{
    [XmlAttribute("num")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("hotel")]
    public List<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel
{
    [XmlAttribute("num")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("item")]
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HotelData));
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
        {
            var data = (HotelData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(data.Id);
            foreach (var hotel in data.Hotels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("num: {0}, item:{1}", hotel.Id, hotel.Item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I don't need to set XmlArray in [XmlElement("hotel")]
    public List<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; } ?

Comment: Why won't you need? Your XML seems to contain an array of hotels. At least the example you have shown here. But maybe your actual XML is different, is it?